# How to not add an item's price when it is out of stock?

Tags: python, class, inventory-management

The `Product` class has been defined.

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, code, description, price=1.0, quantity=1):
        self.code = int(code)
        self.description = str(description)
        self.price = float(price)
        self.quantity = int(quantity)
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.quantity == 0:
            return ("Code = {}, {} - Out of Stock".format(self.code, self.description))
        else:
            return ("Code = {}, {}, ${:.2f}, quantity = {}".format(self.code, self.description, self.price, self.quantity))
```

I have also defined another class - `PurchaseProduct` Here I am having problem in the `purchasing(self, search_code)` method. what this method does is it takes a code value as a parameter and decrements the quantity value by 1 if the the search code exists in the shopping items list and the item is available (i.e. quantity > 0). It also prints the description and price (2 decimal places) of that item. The method invokes the search() method.

If the search code item exists but it is not available, the method should print the message 'XXX Out of Stock!' where XXX indicates the item code. If the search ode does not exist, the method should print the message "XXX Not Found!" where XXX indicates the item code. Finally, the method returns the price of the item if the item exists and is available.

```
class PurchaseProduct:
    def __init__(self, filename = 'items.txt'):
        self.filename = filename
        PurchaseProduct.items_list = []
        
    def read_item_file(self):
        try:
            file = open(self.filename, 'r')
            res = file.read()
            content_list = res.split('\n')
            
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print ("ERROR: The file '{}' does not exist.".format(self.filename))
            return 0
            
        else:
            file.close()
            return res_list
    
    def load_items(self):
        try:
            list_items = self.read_item_file()
            for item in list_items:
                code, desc, price, quant = item.split(',')
                self.items_list.append(Product(code= int(code), description= str(desc), price=price, quantity= int(quant)))
        except:
            list_items = []
            
    def search(self, search_code): 
        self.search_code = search_code
        for index in range(len(PurchaseProduct.items_list)):
            if PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].code == self.search_code:
                return (PurchaseProduct.items_list[index])
   

     def purchasing(self, search_code): #ISSUE HERE
            self.search_code = search_code
            for index in range(len(PurchaseProduct.items_list)):
                if self.search(search_code) != None: 
                    if PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].quantity >= 1:
                        print ("{} ${:.2f}".format(PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].description,PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].price))
                        PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].quantity -= 1
                        return PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].price
                    else:
                        print ("{} Out of Stock!".format(PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].code))
                        return PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].price
            else:
                print ("{} Not Found!".format(self.search_code))
                return PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].price
```

Test:

```
shop_cart = PurchaseProduct('item.txt')
shop.load_items()
cost = shop_cart.purchasing(11)
cost += shop_cart.purchasing(11)
print(cost)
cost += shop_cart.purchasing(11)
print(cost)
cost += shop_cart.purchasing(999)
print(cost)
```

Expected Output:

```
Coca Cola Soft Drink 500ml $4.00
Coca Cola Soft Drink 500ml $4.00
8.0
11 Out of Stock!
8.0
999 Not Found!
8.0
```

Actual Output:

```
Coca Cola Soft Drink 500ml $4.00
Coca Cola Soft Drink 500ml $4.00
8.0
11 Out of Stock!
12.0
999 Not Found!
14.0
```

Contents of `'item.txt'`:

```
11,Coca Cola Soft Drink 500ml,4,2
12,L & P Soft Drink Lemon & Paeroa 500ml,4,9
13,V Blue Drink can 500mL,3.5,8
14,V Vitalise Energy Drink 500ml,3.5,5
15,Pump Water NZ Spring 750ml,2.5,9
16,Twix Chocolate Bar 50g,2.5,12
17,Nestle Kit Kat Chocolate Bar 4 Finger, 2.4,15
18,Snickers Chocolate Bar 50g,2,11
19,Cadbury Chocolate Bar Crunchie 50g, 2,13
20,Cadbury Picnic Chocolate Bar 46g,2,15
```

Comment: You got your answers, but why wouldn't you use a dictionary to keep track of the products as a function of the `search_code`. You have loops inside loops that could be dramatically simplified by key/value searches.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822, and possibly let [your classmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830942/how-can-i-get-the-price-of-an-item-in-the-purchasing-method-to-not-add-when-an-i) know that we notice when the same question about the same assignment is asked twice in a short period. Your instructor will probably notice identical code, too.

Comment: @deponovo Can you provide an answer or link to similar question to teach _dictionary_  (key/value) and the concept of _lookup_ in Python ️ Bet the whole class could learn from that.

Comment: @hc_dev I would not like to advertise for any specific source (web or books). There plenty of (good) options on the first hits from a web search, for instance. Using the official docs is always a good start as in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: @yowhatsup123 I guess some answer answers your question better than the other and it would be nice if you mark the better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, it seems that you can simply return `0` when the item is out of stock, as it won't change the total cost.

```py
if PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].quantity >= 1:
    print("{} ${:.2f}".format(PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].description,PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].price))
    PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].quantity -= 1
    return PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].price
else:
    print ("{} Out of Stock!".format(PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].code))
    return 0
```

Comment: A lesson could be: (a) to adapt/reuse pre-defined `__str__` of Product and/or (b) to reduce random-access by using a locally scoped variable `item = PurchaseProduct.items_list[index]`.

Comment: @hc_dev These are valuable suggestions but StackOverflow is not a place for code review; that's what https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for. Hence, I just answered the OP's question with minimal modifications to their code. Anything else is out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

#### Price if on stock, otherwise 0

I would:

- extract the found `item` for multiple reuse later
- separate the unhappy path with a [*guard clause*](https://medium.com/@scadge/if-statements-design-guard-clauses-might-be-all-you-need-67219a1a981a) (also known as *guard statement*) (inverting the if)
- use *f-strings* for formatting (Python 3.6+ required)

```py
item = PurchaseProduct.items_list[index]  # to reuse later
# guard statement, fail fast
if item.quantity < 1:
    print(f"{item.code} Out of Stock!")
    return 0

# the expected, happy case
print(f"{item.description}: {item.price:.2f}$")
item.quantity -= 1
return item.price
```

#### Structural improvement

Maybe define a function for that functionality (reduce stock and return the price). Looking in your code how the `index` is determined, we can see it in the `search` function, where the found item is returned as:
`PurchaseProduct.items_list[index]`

We take this into consideration when designing further item-operations, like the function to withdraw from stock or evaluate a price:

```py
def priceAndWithdrawFromStock(item):
   if item.quantity < 1:
       print(f"{item.code} Out of Stock!")
       return 0

   print(f"{item.description}: {item.price:.2f}$")
   item.quantity -= 1
   return item.price
```

Then use it in the loop or what is left after refactoring the body of  `purchasing` function:

```py
def purchasing(self, search_code): #ISSUE HERE
    found_item = self.search(search_code)  # either item or None returned
    if not found_item:  # guard for not-found
        print (f"{search_code} Not Found!")  # safer to rely on param instead of self.search
        return 0

    return priceAndWithdrawFromStock(found_item)
```

Note: the guard-clause for not-found (inverted if), the f-string, no for-loop needed, `var == None` is equal to `not var` (so is `if var` equal to `if var != None`)

.. and removed the duplicate assignment of an attribute, because it was already set by `search` function before:
`self.search_code = search_code`

#### Reuse the `Product` string

Look at the pre-defined Product class, particularly the [dunder-method](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/topics/what-are-dunder-methods/) `__str__` which returns a string representation of your product or item.

You can reuse it in some cases, e.g. to print like `print(item)`

- instead `print ("{} Out of Stock!".format(PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].code))`
- instead `print ("{} ${:.2f}".format(PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].description,PurchaseProduct.items_list[index].price))`

As long as the `item` exists (`item != None`) Python's built-in `print` function will invoke the `__str__` method obtain the string representation of the item for printing (independent of stock-status, see the `if` in `__str__`).

#### See also

- Martin Fowler, Refactoring: [Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)
- Python docs: [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), with examples

Comment: A rather simple question resulted in a chirurgical answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

This should be an easy fix. Just replace the last line of the `purchasing` function with

```
return 0
```

Since you only want to return the price if it exists.